# Varying input arguments in pandas groupby operation using lambda

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset with many variables that looks like this:

[image: asdfasdfasdf]

I am grouping some columns of these data by zip code using the following code:

```
variables_to_used = ['Var1','Var2','Var3']
df.groupby('ZipCode')[variables_to_used].apply(
    lambda x: [list(x['Var1']), list(x['Var2']), list(x['Var3'])]).apply(pd.Series).to_numpy()
```

and I am getting this output:

```
array([[list([12, 3, 324]), list([1, 324, 43]), list([34, 34, 4])],
   [list([6, 56]), list([67, 38]), list([68, 58])]], dtype=object)
```

How can I implement this code for any list "variables_to_used" without explicitly including the variables in the lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby('ZipCode')[variables_to_used].apply(
    lambda x: [list(x[var]) for var in variables_to_used]).apply(pd.Series).to_numpy()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

don need to use lambda func

melt & groupby

```
variables_to_used = ['Var1','Var2','Var3']
(df.melt('ZipCode', value_vars=variables_to_used)
   .groupby(['ZipCode', 'variable']).agg(list).unstack().to_numpy())
```

**Example**

and plz dont provide example by image.
[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

we need code or text for solving problem

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'ZipCode': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 'Store': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Var1': [12, 3, 324, 6, 56], 
         'Var2': [1, 324, 43, 67, 38], 'Var3': [34, 34, 4, 68, 58]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```